# Unable to consume libraries from bin folder

Tags: asp.net, reference, amazon-cognito, libraries

I have a .NET website with some ASP and ASPX pages. I want to reference a library from the AWS SDK, but because I don't have `proj` and `sln` files, and Visual Studio is not installed on the server, I'm unable to access the libraries. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I added `AWSSDK.Core.dll` and `AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider.dll` to the bin directory of my website root, and I'm trying to import the namespaces from the above libraries in my `aspx.vb` file.

```vb
<% Import Namespace = "Amazon" %>
<% Import Namespace = "Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider" %>
<% Import Namespace = "Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model" %>
```

However, I receive this error message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK.Core' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Although I have the libraries in my bin directory.

I also tried importing the assemblies first:

```vb
<%@ Assembly Name="AWSSDK.Core" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider" %>
    
<%@ Import Namespace="Amazon" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model" %>
```

But I got the same error. What could be missing in this configuration that prevents it from picking up the library from the bin directory?

Comment: You can try registering the assembly within the web.config.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987152/register-assembly-in-asp-net-vs-2005-and-web-config